# Why does clicking a select dropdown inside a form embedded in a modal dialog close the modal only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

Platform: Windows 10. Firefox 119.

I built a modal dialog in a more complex project and came across this bug.
The other browsers I'm testing on are Chrome and Edge. These don't have the bug. The following code is a highly-simplified version of my original project.

In Firefox, as soon as you click on the select dropdown, the modal closes, not allowing the form to be submitted.

Has anyone else come across this? Has anyone got a fix?

**Note**: fixed - see answer below.
Updated Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/najfiddle/1uxw2Le8/9/

```js
/** Form **/
const form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.reset()
  modal.close()
})


/** Modal **/
const launchModalBtn = document.getElementById("launch-modal")
const modal = document.getElementById("modal")

launchModalBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.showModal()
})

/* modal backdrop */
modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const modalDimensions = modal.getBoundingClientRect()

  if (
    e.clientX < modalDimensions.left ||
    e.clientX > modalDimensions.right ||
    e.clientY < modalDimensions.top ||
    e.clientY > modalDimensions.bottom
  ) {
    form.reset()
    modal.close()
  }
})
```

```css
/*Form */

form,
form>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}


/** Modal */

.modal {
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 4rem;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.modal::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(9, 9, 70, 0.8);
  z-index: 40;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="launch-modal">
        Open modal
    </button>
<dialog id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form id="form">
      <div class="word-phrase">
        <label for="term" class="term">Word</label>

        <input id="term" type="text">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="definition">Definition </label>
        <textarea id="definition" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="language-select">Choose language</label>
        <select id="language-select" name="language-select">
          <option value="en">English</option>
          <option value="fr">French</option>
          <option value="de">German</option>
          <option value="it">Italian</option>
          <option value="la">Latin</option>
          <option value="es">Spanish</option>
          <option value="und">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Clicking the select returns 0 for the e.clientX and Y in firefox

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? Is there any way to counteract or accommodate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the issue. There is a similar issue with drag: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521#c80

The issue is: you get a clientX and Y which are 0 when you click the select or its options.

The safest solution is to not look at the bounding box but just check if the click was inside the form

Tested in Fx 118 and 119 on Windows 10

```js
/** Form **/
const form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  console.log("submitted")
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.reset()
  modal.close()
})


/** Modal **/
const launchModalBtn = document.getElementById("launch-modal")
const modal = document.getElementById("modal")

launchModalBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.showModal()
})

/* modal backdrop */
modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const formClicked = e.target.closest('form'); 
  if (!formClicked) { //click was NOT inside the form
    form.reset()
    modal.close()
  }
})
```

```css
/*Form */

form,
form>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}


/** Modal */

.modal {
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 4rem;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.modal::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(9, 9, 70, 0.8);
  z-index: 40;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="launch-modal">
        Open modal
    </button>
<dialog id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form id="form">
      <div class="word-phrase">
        <label for="term" class="term">Word</label>

        <input id="term" type="text">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="definition">Definition </label>
        <textarea id="definition" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="language-select">Choose language</label>
        <select id="language-select" name="language-select">
          <option value="en">English</option>
          <option value="fr">French</option>
          <option value="de">German</option>
          <option value="it">Italian</option>
          <option value="la">Latin</option>
          <option value="es">Spanish</option>
          <option value="und">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

The code above will only close the modal if you click OUTSIDE the blue area if you use closest("form") and green area if you use .closest(".modal-content")
[image]

Comment: I tried your code. It made things slightly better: the dropdown list now displays. However, when you click on an item, the modal closes.

Comment: Sorry, I answered based on your first iteration. It works!  Thanks :)

Comment: On my computer, the modal has a margin of several cm. See image I have pasted

Comment: I've moved the padding from the .modal to the form. This solves the problem.I've updated the demo on  jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/najfiddle/1uxw2Le8/8/

Comment: You can just change to  `const contentClicked = e.target.closest('.modal-content')
  if (!contentClicked) {` if you want reset and close outside the padding of the content

Comment: One thing I'm still having trouble understanding how it works: .closest() looks for ancestors, not descendants. Your code has .closest("form") but the form is inside the modal. How can modal.addEventListnener ... formElement.closest("form") workd?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try and say that more clearly.  const formClicked = e.target.closest("form") is defined within modal.addEventListener. e.target is the modal. How can the modal find the closest form when it actually wraps the form, i.e. it's the parent of the form not the other way round?

Comment: e is the event. Where you click. If you click inside the form, the event will have a closest("form") if you click outside the form anywhere, the e.closest("form") will be null which is falsy which mean that `if (!formClicked)` is true when you click anywhere  in the modal outside the form

Comment: Now I understand, thank you.